# Returning an object of one of two types

Tags: php, oop

I have function:

```
/**
* @return NewActionResponse
*/
public function makeSth(): NewActionResponse
```

Now I want to add optional param but then response type is different.

```
/**
* @param int|null $param
*
* @return NewActionWithParamResponse
*/
public function makeSth(?int $param=null): NewActionWithParamResponse
```

What is the best practise to return one of two types if function is quite large but second version add only one line to logic and the response from an external server is significantly different?

Comment: [union types](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/union_types_v2) might be an interesting read

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

Use a `Response` interface, which will be implemented by both (all) response types and use the interface as the return type.

```php
interface Response {...}

class NewActionResponse implements Response {...}
class NewActionWithParamResponse implements Response {...}

public function makeSth(?int $param = null): Response {...}
```

**Solution 2:**

PHP 8 supports union types: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/union_types_v2.

```php
public function makeSth(?int $param = null): NewActionResponse|NewActionWithParamResponse {...}
```

- From a pure OOP point of view, the first version is more recommended. Most of the times all response types will have common methods (e.g. `getBody()`), which you can enforce using a common interface.
  If there's also common behavior, you can use instead of / additional to the interface a common abstract class ancestor.

**Solution 3:**

If a single optional param causes such a different response, you might want to consider using another makeSth method altogether:

```php
public function makeSth(): NewActionResponse {...}
public function makeSthElse(int $param): NewActionWithParamResponse {...}
```